# Concert Events Data

Tags: data-request, api

I am looking for an historic dataset of concert events. I have tried the last.fm api but the query endpoint I need appears to be broken:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409011/last-fm-geo-getevents-returns-invalid-method-no-method-with-that-name-in-this

I have also tried the eventbrite api but it didn't have much in the way of major concerts. Basically, I need a list of concerts that occurred within a given city/country. I would need the dataset to go back to January 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Setlist.fm](http://www.setlist.fm/) offers this data; here's [Madison Square Gardens 2015 Schedule](http://www.setlist.fm/search?query=Madison+Square+Garden&year=2015) just to show you an example of the data you requested. You can either scrape or use [Setlist.fm API](http://api.setlist.fm/docs/index.html)